# Estimate Shipping and Tax in product view

Tags: shipping, forms

I made the block `checkout/cart/shipping.phtml` visible in `catalog/product/view.phtml`.
I need this to estimate the shipping value in the product view.

The checkout/cart/shipping.phtml work very well in the `/checkout/cart.phtml`,
But it does not work in `catalog/product/view.phtml`.
Can anyone help me to make this work?

This is the site: http://oxiban.com.br

Answer (score 1):

for finding shipping charges You may need complete module for this :

**form.phtml**

```
<?php if ($this->isEnabled()): ?>
<div class="block block-shipping-estimate">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getTitle(); ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
    <p class="block-subtitle"><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getDes(); ?></p>
    <ul class="shipping-estimation-form" id="shipping-estimation-form">
        <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('country')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="estimate_country" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Country') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <?php echo Mage::getBlockSingleton('directory/data')->getCountryHtmlSelect(
                            ($this->getFieldValue('country') ? $this->getFieldValue('country') : $this->getConfig()->getDefaultCountry()),
                            'estimate[country_id]',
                            'estimate_country'
                        );
                    ?>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php else: ?>
            <input type="hidden" id="estimate_country" name="estimate[country_id]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getConfig()->getDefaultCountry())?>" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('region')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="estimate_region_id"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('region')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('region')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <select id="estimate_region_id" name="estimate[region_id]" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('State/Province') ?>" style="display:none;"<?php echo ($this->isFieldRequired('region') ? ' class="validate-select"' : '') ?>>
                        <option value=""><?php echo  Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Please select an option') ?></option>
                    </select>
                   <script type="text/javascript">
                   //<![CDATA[
                       $('estimate_region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getFieldValue('region_id')); ?>');
                   //]]>
                   </script>
                   <input type="text" id="estimate_region" name="estimate[region]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('region')) ?>"  title="<?php echo  Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text" style="display:none;" />
               </div>
            </li>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
                new RegionUpdater('estimate_country', 'estimate_region', 'estimate_region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>);
            //]]>
            </script>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if($this->isFieldVisible('city')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="city"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('city')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('city')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo  Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('City') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input class="input-text<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('city')):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" id="estimate_city" type="text" name="estimate[city]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('city')) ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('postcode')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="estimate_postcode"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input class="input-text validate-postcode<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('postcode')):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="estimate_postcode" name="estimate[postcode]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('postcode')) ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
       <?php endif; ?>
       <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('coupon_code')): ?>
            <li class="item">
                <label for="estimate_coupon_code"<?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('coupon_code')):?> class="required" <?php endif;?>><?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('coupon_code')):?><em>*</em><?php endif;?><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Coupon Code') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input class="input-text <?php if ($this->isFieldRequired('coupon_code')):?> required-entry<?php endif;?>" type="text" id="estimate_coupon_code" name="estimate[coupon_code]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFieldValue('coupon_code')) ?>" />
                </div>
            </li>
       <?php endif; ?>
       <?php if ($this->isFieldVisible('cart')): ?>
            <li class="item radio">
                <label for="estimate_cart_yes"><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Include Cart Items') ?></label>
                <div class="input-box">
                    <input type="radio" id="estimate_cart_yes" name="estimate[cart]" value="1" <?php if ($this->useShoppingCart()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif;?> /><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Yes') ?>
                    <input type="radio" id="estimate_cart_no" name="estimate[cart]" value="0" <?php if (!$this->useShoppingCart()): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif;?> /> <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('No') ?>
                </div>
            </li>
       <?php elseif ($this->useShoppingCart()):?>
            <input id="estimate_cart_yes" type="hidden" name="estimate[cart]" value="1" />
       <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('shipping-estimation-form');</script>
    <div class="actions">
        <span class="please-wait f-left" id="shipping-estimate-loading-message" style="display:none;">
            <?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Loading rates...') ?>
        </span>
        <div class="f-right">
            <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->getButton(); ?>" onclick="estimateProductShipping()" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('webdevlopers_productpageshipping')->__('Get a Quote') ?></span></span></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="shipping-estimate-results" style="display:none">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function estimateProductShipping()
{
    var estimationUrl = '<?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape($this->getEstimateUrl());?>';
    var items = $$(['.shipping-estimation-form input',
                    '.shipping-estimation-form select',
                    '#product_addtocart_form input',
                    '#product_addtocart_form select']);

    var validationResult = true;

    // Check the valid input
    if (!items.map(Validation.validate).all()) {
        return;
    }

    var parameters = Form.serializeElements(items, true);
    $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').show();
    $('shipping-estimate-results').hide();
    new Ajax.Updater('shipping-estimate-results', estimationUrl, {
        parameters: parameters,
        onComplete: function() {
            $('shipping-estimate-loading-message').hide();
            $('shipping-estimate-results').show();
        }
    });

}
//]]>
</script>
<?php endif;?>
```

you can see the complete module :

https://github.com/5mehulhelp5/MagentoExtensions/tree/master/Magento%20Display%20Shipping%20estimation%20Block%20in%20Product%20view%20page

Comment: Hey user9999,

Thanks for your reply.
I installed the extension and it does not work. I think that the problem is my template, but I am not sure.
I will work in the extension and try to make it work.